# Laravel 5.5 Worker Memory Issue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Laravel worker set up on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It is a t2.micro instance.

I am noticing that whenever the worker gets touched from AWS SQS, the memory on the EC2 instance spikes to 99% consumption and then comes back down.

This does not happen on any other instance, just this specific worker instance.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that only one worker is running? Chances are you are executing `php artisan queue:work` multiple times as a cron job, where as it should only be executed once as a daemon and monitored with `supervisor`.

Comment: That is a good point but with elastic beanstalk and Laravel it is troublesome to run supervisor.

Comment: Have you given a chance to this:

https://github.com/FoxxMD/laravel-elasticbeanstalk-queue-worker

Comment: No, I used a different worker plugin. I will have a look at that one. Thanks!

Comment: I have found this to happen even without a CRON being run on the worker. Even just from a simple job dispatch from the web environment to the worker environment as a test, the memory maxes out on the worker and sends the environment into a degraded state.